# trash: cannot trash regular file

Tags: command-line, permissions, rm

I'm trying to avoid using `rm` so I don't delete anything permanently. I'm using the utility function `trash`, but it keeps telling me `trash: cannot trash regular file`. Why can't I delete these files? They are, for example, csv files I've created in a program.

```
$ ls -l | grep filename
-rw-rw-r--  1 username usergroup 298025 Sep 23 02:33 filename.csv
```

Running it with the `-v` flag gives:

```
trash: found unusable .Trash dir (should be a dir): /.Trash
trash: Failed to trash filename.csv in /.Trash/1005, because :[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.Trash'
trash: Failed to trash filename.csv in /.Trash-1005, because :[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.Trash-1005'
trash: cannot trash regular file `filename.csv'
```

I've noticed another feature too. I'm trying to `trash` the file from a directory that isn't mine. But if I `mv` the file to `~`, I can `trash` it successfully there.

Comment: try using it with `sudo`

Comment: Start the command again with the `-v` switch `trash -v filename.csv`

Comment: And **DON'T** use `sudo`

Comment: Maybe you want to try and use `gvfs-trash` instead?

Answer (score 7):

GNOMEish file managers need a place to put the trashed files.

- Deleted files on your "home" partition go to:  `/home/$USER/.local/share/Trash`
- Deleted files on other partitions can't be copied "home" for performance and space reasons.

So it tries to put them in the `/[partition mount]/.Trash-$UID` folder.  Without rw access to that folder, no trash.

Run this bash in the partition root as the user who needs a trash.

```
sudo mkdir .Trash-$UID && sudo chown $USER:$USER .Trash-$UID
```

You can delete this folder and secure the partition / to disable that feature.

```
sudo rm -rf /[partition mount]/.Trash-xxxx
sodo chown root:root /[partition mount]/
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to trash a file from a directory where you don't have write access. You won't be able to do that. Look at the error you are getting:

```
trash: Failed to trash filename.csv in /.Trash/1005, because :[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.Trash'
```

you either i) don't have permission to write to the directory containing the file (which you need to do in order to remove a file from it) and/or ii) don't have the right to write to `./.Trash` since it's not your directory.

Comment: Thanks. Is that hypothesis consistent with being able to `rm` the file (which I can do) but not `trash` it?

Comment: @Hatshepsut yes. Check the permissions of `/.Trash/1005`. That's where you're attempting to write to.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a `.Trash` folder in root of all of my mount points (could be seen by `df` command), not just `home` folder.